# Populate a select box with results generated from another select box

Tags: ember.js

Another new-to-ember question - I have a component that contains a select (call it type) object.  When a type is selected, I want to take the selected type, make a REST call using the selected type to return records, and populate a second select object in another component with the returned records.  There are too many subtypes to get during initialization (the type list is retrieved during initialization). The process currently is: 1) select value type is chosen 2) type chosen is sent to parent route and set there 3) value chosen is used by REST service to get list of subtypes.  All this works now, but I have been unable to set the the component select to the subtypes retrieved by the REST service.  Been beating my head against this for a while now, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Additional comment - I inherited this application, so some things may not be set up normal to an Ember application.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when the REST call returns, set the result as a prop on the controller. Then, bind that prop as the second select's `content`.

```
// some/route.js
fetchBlah(param) {
  return Ember.$.getJSON('/some/path', {some: param}).then(result => {
    this.controller.set('fetchedData', result);
  });
}

// some/template.hbs

{{view 'select' content=fetchedData}}
```

Comment: Thanks - question: how could I do this if I want to set the result from a route and not a controller?

Comment: you can access controllers from routes with `this.controller` or `this.controllerFor(routeName)`

Comment: Unfortunately, in this design I inherited, there is no controller.  Everything is done in routes.

Comment: I used the above code in the route, but no luck.  The data does not change in the component.  This is the component template:
    {{
      view 
      "select" 
      content=selectedEntities
      value=selectedEntity 
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.primaryValue"
      prompt="Select Entity..."
    }}